# How ordering service in Hyperledger make blocks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger fabric suppose Peer1 and Peer2 are communicating using channel1 (Transaction1) and Peer3 and Peer4 are communicating using channel2 (Transaction2). My question is once Transaction1 and Transaction2 arrived at ordering service, will it be placed in same Block by Orderer? If yes, then will this block be broadcasted to all peers in network who are not related to Transaction1 and Transaction2?

Please provide any specific link which explain this concept in details.

Answer (score 2):

Channels in Hyperledger Fabric designed to provide data segregation, that is to separate information to provide confidentiality and decouple information based on business rules.

In your example both transactions will enter different blocks, since each channel maintains separate ledger and therefore there is no need for total order. Hence transactions for separate channels ordered independently.

For more information please take a look [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channels.html).

Answer (score 0):

Each channel is a separate chain of blocks, so in your example Transaction1 and Transaction2 will not appear in the same block.

If TransactionA and TransactionB were both submitted on channel1 in quick succession they could both be ordered in the same block.  However if there is a delay between the 2 Transactions they will be ordered into separate blocks.  (I don't know what the delay time is to create separate blocks but it is probably configurable.)

You could try installing the [Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) on top of your fabric to see the blocks and transactions.

Comment: You can find the configuration about block creation at `Orderer` section in file `configtx.yaml`. It includes    (1) BatchTimeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch.    (2) MaxMessageCount: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch.   (3) AbsoluteMaxBytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for the serialized messages in a batch.    (4) PreferredMaxBytes